# Determine where an access database is stored

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm logging onto a machine in a corporate network, which has Access on it.
When I open Access there's a Jet database in the recently used files list which I can open.

Is there a simple way of determining where this database is stored.  It's not a case of simply searching the machine as I believe it maybe stored on a network share.

I've tried clicking save-as and that does not take me to the file location.
The machine has Access 2010 installed.

Comment: The recently opened file menu provides the full path to the file.

Comment: Ah you're right.  I had to hover the mouse cursor over the file and then it gave me the full path.

Comment: I've just checked on my own machine and as of Access 2013 it's a lot clearer and puts it underneath the file name without the need for the hover.